# Test spring boot app with servlet parameters in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test

In application.yml there is the following parameter:

```
server:
    context-parameters:
        appCode: MYAPPCODE
```

This parameter is read by a third-party library. When running on embedded Tomcat, the parameter is available in the ServletContext. However, when running a test on SpringRunner, the ServletContext has no parameter.

Here is the relevant part of the test class.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class RestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    private void create() {
        String content = createContent();
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/entity/create").content(content))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("id").isNumber());
    }

}
```

How can I configure the test class so that the mocked ServletContext is set with the context parameters from the application.yml?

Currently, to overcome the problem, I did the following workaround in the test class.

```java
@Autowired
private ServletContext servletContext;

@Autowired
private ServerProperties serverProperties;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    Map<String, String> params = serverProperties.getContextParameters();
    new InitParameterConfiguringServletContextInitializer(params)
        .onStartup(servletContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I configure the test class so that the mocked `ServletContext`
>   is set with the context parameters from the `application.yml`?

AFAIK, that is currently not possible when using `WebEnvironment.MOCK` (i.e., the default mode for `@SpringBootTest`) since the `MockServletContext` used by the  `WebApplicationContext` configured by Spring Boot is *plain vanilla* (i.e., not populated with external values).

Thus, your "workaround" is the only solution.

Comment: Sam Brannen, thank you for your answer. Since the mocked servlet context is set with the filters I add with spring security, I was hoping it would be possible for it to be set with the context params in application.yml through some nice and clear config annotation.